# Desabilitar função submit ao aparecer mensagem de erro

Tags: jquery, formulário, magento

Como eu faço para "bloquear" ou "desabilitar" o botão do formulário ao aparecer a mensagem de error?

**Input**

```
<input style="height:24px;" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />

                   <p style="color: #ee001c" id="para" name="para" class="ok"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
   $j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#email").focus(function() {}).blur(function() { 
        $j("contactForm").submit(function () { return false; });
        //atribuindo o valor do campo
        var sEmail  = $j("#email").val();
        // filtros
        var emailFilter=/^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
        var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/
        // condição
        if(!(emailFilter.test(sEmail))||sEmail.match(illegalChars)){
            $j("#para").show().removeClass("ok").addClass("erro")
            .text('Informe um endereço de email válido. Por exemplo, exemplo@domain.com.');
        }else{
        }
    });
    $j('#email').focus(function(){
        $j("#para").hide();
    });
   });
```

**Solução**

```
        function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
              return re.test(email);
            }

            function validate() {
              $j("#para").text("");
              var email = $j("#email").val();
              if (validateEmail(email)) {
            return true;
              } else {
            $j("#para").text("Informe um endereço de email válido. Por exemplo, exemplo@domain.com.");
            return false;
              }

            }

            $j(".validate").bind("blur", validate);
            $j("#validate").bind("click", validate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de adicionar a mensagem de erro, adicione a propriedade `"disabled"` ao botão.

```
$("#email").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // adicionando a propriedade para desabilitar o botão.
e.preventDefault(); // parando a execução do formulário
```

Comment: Eu adiciono isso ali no if? Depois da mensagem?

Comment: Depois de: $j("#para").show().removeClass("ok").addClass("erro").text('Informe um endereço de email válido. Por exemplo, exemplo@domain.com.');

Comment: Consegui de outro jeito, do modo que você disse eu não obtive sucesso, não sei se implementei mal ou o que.